# Make se.com an alias for stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hyperlinks

I think it would be good to have `se.com` as a shortcut for Stack Exchange sites.  For example:

```
cooking.se.com
english.se.com
math.se.com
```

Comment: Do you also happen to own the `se.com` TLD? If yes; I can see why you would approve of this. If no; I can't see how you'd achieve this without manually editing your hosts file (which you can already do)

Comment: might as well acquire the Swedish domains, e.g. http://math.se

Comment: @David Hedlund no I don't own the domain, I just think that stackexchange it's kinda long

Comment: @Navarium: You can bookmark the sites or use a http://tinyurl.com/...

Comment: I still want to shorten `meta.programmers.stackexchange.com`. A site that has a 34 character long domain is really unappealing

Comment: @Tobias, that was proposed and rejected

Comment: `sx.com` might be for sale and not totally unreachable with SO's funding. As might `se.org`

Comment: I still think this could be a good idea. Unfortnuately, [sxe.com](http://sxe.com) is already taken, but for instance sxe.name or sxe.technology is not ([source](https://www.gandi.net/domain/suggest)). I did not came up with a better idea, but some nice alias / redirection would be a plus.

Comment: Ok I [justsaw](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69591/262759) that .com extension were "mandatory". But that answer is 5 years old: did the orientation changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Sites don't receive their own .com domain name anymore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) until they get enough traffic, with the notable exception of AskUbuntu.

Also, as se.com is already owned by someone, it is impossible to do what you suggest.

Comment: two-character domain names are _extremely_ hard to come by.

Comment: What about other domains?

Comment: @TheLQ - sexchange.com?  :)

Comment: Technically, this answer is incorrect at this point in time!

Comment: @NickCraver Who said something stops being funny after being 6 years old?