# Can we shorten Stack Exchange URLs by using .se domains?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, subdomains

I have encountered a problem when trying to introduce new people to the SE network: they can't remember Stack Exchange.

So, for example, I might tell a non-tech user: "You should ask your question on this cooking website, it's called `cooking.stackexchange.com`." They remember the cooking part very easily (or the diy, or gaming, etc..), but they tend to forget the `stackexchange` part.

So what I propose is that we buy domains for all Area 51 site proposals that end in `*.se`. So, for example, `cooking.stackexchange.com` would be magically transformed into `cooking.se`.

I understand that it isn't a `.com` but it could be forwarded to `*.stackexchange.com`

---

**Most (*if not all*) of the domains should be available** since this is a [Swedish domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.se). I'm not 100% sure if non-Swedish compaines/people can register these domains [but it looks like they can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.se#Post_2003_system).

<sup>This is not the same as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63618/make-se-com-an-alias-for-stackexchange-com) since it proposes we use `*.se.com`. Also the accepted answer for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63618/make-se-com-an-alias-for-stackexchange-com) was basically that "all sites will get their own .com once they leave beta," which we now know isn't the plan.</sup>

Comment: FYI, cooking has a redirect from http://seasonedadvice.com.  Obviously that doesn't apply to every SE.

Comment: @Aarobot: Yeah, just like webapps has http://nothingtoinstall.com. I actually still use that domain to get to the site because it's just stuck in my head.

Comment: I suggested talking to the owners of `se.com` a few months back. They rent out `xyz.se.com` names. Most meaningful swedish .se names are already taken, among them cooking. Most popular english terms are taken in all TLDs around the world

Comment: This was asked again just recently, and the team responded: [Can we get \*.se CNAMEs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312255/can-we-get-se-cnames)

Answer (score 1):

This was basically declined in a long-ago post that said the team was only interested in `.com` domains.

EDIT:
Actually, turns out it was a post on the SO blog: [Domain Names](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)

> 1. Please don’t think that it’s necessary to use a domain name that reflects something going wrong. We picked the name “Stack Overflow” because it has some meaning for real programmers, not because it reflected a bug or problem. “Super User” is just as good a name. I get depressed by all these suggestions of “BurntChicken.com”, “LostYarmulke.com”, and “FallenArches.com” (for former owners of McDonald’s franchises, of course).
>    2. Look for jargon that has meaning to the group of people you want to attract. Insider jargon is the duck call of insiders. Look at me! If I can say “contributory negligence,” I must be a real lawyer!
>    3. **.coms are a million times better than other TLDs.**
>    4. A domain name should be readable over the phone. Even on AT&T Wireless. Tricky spellings are always a bad idea. Similarly, dashes reek of desperation.
>    5. Long names are not the end of the world. Using two or three words (or a couple of digits) is a good way to find available domains.

(emphasis mine)

To be fair, other parts of this post were overturned after a pretty big community outcry; see the later blog post [Domain Names: The Wrong Question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/).

EDIT 2:
Looks like this proposal was actually made in [a comment to that first blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/#comment-48438) by Vortico, too:

> The .se TLD (Sweden, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.se ) could be used as a pseudo-URL shortener for SE sites, much like Google uses goo.gl to redirect to certain company pages.

> Imagine typing “baking.se” to redirect to “bakingoverflow.com”. This would not only strengthen the brand of StackExchange but make the address easier to type and relate to other SE sites.

Comment: baking.se is in fact [available](http://www.iis.se/domaner/free?q=baking), but many many other important SE domains are not (cooking, bicycling...)

Comment: ".coms are a million times better than other TLDs.": That means we just have to register a million Swedish domains per site.